# Use a variable from one IF - Statement into the other IF - Statement in PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a variable $target inside an IF - Statement in my login.php. I created the folders and sub-folders based on this variable. Now i want to move the uploaded file to this location. How can I do that?

here is the code

```
$upload = "E:/demons";

if(isset($_POST['userid'], $_POST['pid']))
         {
         $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
         $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE uname = '$userid' and pword = '$pid'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  



        echo "公司".'<br/>';
        echo $row['client'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';
        echo "第".'<br/>';
        echo '<a href="upload.html"/>'.$row['day1'].'</a>'.'<br/>';


        $target = $upload.'/'.$row['week'].'/'.$row['day1'].'/'.$row['client'].'/'.$row['brand'].'/'.$row['sc'].'/';


        $imagename = $row['week'].'.'.$row['day1'].'.'.$row['client'].'.'.$row['brand'].'.'.$row['sc'].'.'.'jpg';


                if(!file_exists($target))
                    {
                        mkdir($target,null,true);
                    }
        }

else if(isset($_FILES['image']))
        {
        $image = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        echo $image;
        //$target4 = $upload.'/'.$row['week'].'/'.$row['day1'].'/'.$row['client'].'/'.$row['brand'].'/'.$row['sc'].'/';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
        }
        else
            {
                echo "asdfg";
         }
```

Userid and Pid comes from login.html and Image value comes from upload.html

Comment: are you talking about the `move_uploaded_file` at the end ? It mustn't be in the else statement to do that... your code won't be able to execute both blocks. You can change the "else if" into a new if, which will included in the first if (about id and userid). So if userid, pid, and image are set, it will move the uploaded file. Is that what you want ?

Comment: You haven't two `if`s here. You have `if-elseif` and script goes into only one part (PHP basics). In the first `$target` is set, but when first `if` is false, in `elseif` part you have undefined variable.

Comment: I tried using 2 if statements instead of if-elseif. but still no solution. It gives me an error undefined index:$target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$upload = "Your desired location";


//comes from the login.html page
if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid']))
{
  $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
  $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE uname = '$userid' and pword = '$pid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo "Whatever coloumn you wish to echo from database".'<br/>';
  echo $row['col1'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';
  echo "Second Coloumn".'<br/>';
  echo '<a href="upload.html"/>'.$row['col2'].'</a>'.'<br/>';
//create the folders and subfolders based on the data from the database
$target = $upload.'/'.$row['col1'].'/'.$row['col2'].'/'.$row['col3'].'/'.$row['col4'].'/'.$row['col5'].'/';

//for renaming the image.
$imagename = $row['col1'].'.'.$row['col2'].'.'.$row['col3'].'.'.$row['col4'].'.'.$row['col5'].'.'.'jpg';
//create the folders and subfolders
 if(!file_exists($target))
   {
     mkdir($target,null,0777);
   }
//start session and store the value of $target and $imagename in a variable 
session_start();
$_SESSION['str'] = $target;
$_SESSION['img'] = $imagename;

//This comes from other HTML page but to the same PHP.
if(isset($_FILES['image']))

// image upload from upload.html 
// Want the value of target here.
  {

      session_start();
      $_SESSION['str'];
      $_SESSION['img'];
      $image = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

//Move the uploaded file to the desired location.
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img']);

echo "Upload Successful";
```

Hope this would be helpful for all.

Answer (score 0):

Nest the else-if as an if in the first if. Otherwise it won't be executed.

```
$upload = "E:/demons";

if(isset($_POST['userid'], $_POST['pid']))
{
  $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
  $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE uname = '$userid' and pword = '$pid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo "公司".'<br/>';
  echo $row['client'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';
  echo "第".'<br/>';
  echo '<a href="upload.html"/>'.$row['day1'].'</a>'.'<br/>';

  $target = $upload.'/'.$row['week'].'/'.$row['day1'].'/'.$row['client'].'/'.$row['brand'].'/'.$row['sc'].'/';

  $imagename = $row['week'].'.'.$row['day1'].'.'.$row['client'].'.'.$row['brand'].'.'.$row['sc'].'.'.'jpg';

  if(!file_exists($target))
  {
    mkdir($target,null,true);
  }
  if(isset($_FILES['image']))
  {
    $image = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    echo $image;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you sent me. But the image is not uploaded in the desired folder.

Comment: Try this and tell me what it returns - if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      echo "<P>FILE UPLOADED TO: $target</P>";
   } else {
      echo "<P>MOVE UPLOADED FILE  TO: $target FAILED!</P>";
      print_r(error_get_last());
   }

Comment: It gives a blank page. No output is returned. :(

Comment: The value that I am trying to POST from other html form cannot be retrieved into the else block. I mean move_uploaded_file doesnt work. I even tried to hard code the value.

Comment: I got the problem. The first time login.php is executed, it stores the value of $target. But when it is called the second time, $target is a variable with no value. SO it returns an error that move_uploaded_file cannot be moved to empty. Now just wanna find a solution to hold the value of $target for the whole duration till the image is uploaded.

Comment: @AnuragLal Why is the login.php called twice? Is this needed? Otherwise you can try to store the variable in a session.

Comment: I found a solution for this. I used $_SESSION variable to store the value and use it later while moving the uploaded while. How can i display the uploaded image on the page?